# ERROR: dbpath does not exist

Tags: mongodb

I set `dbpath` in mongodb config file:

```
#dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
dbpath=~/data/db
```

Then try start mongodb but got error:

```
ERROR: dbpath (~/data/db) does not exist.
```

Allthough I can check existance of `~/data/db` easy:

```
# cd ~/data/db
user@server:~/data/db# pwd
/root/data/db
```

When I run it...

```
# mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

... got output:

```
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.040 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3786 port=27017 dbpath=/root/data/db 64-bit host=callzone2
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.040 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.6
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.040 [initandlisten] git version: b9925db5eac369d77a3a5f5d98a145eaaacd9673
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.041 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.041 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.041 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/root/data/db" }
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid, terminating
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 dbexit: 
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Oct 15 05:05:49.044 dbexit: really exiting now
```

And client shows that server not started:

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
Tue Oct 15 05:08:22.139 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

When I run in this way...

```
# sudo service mongodb restart
```

... got output in mongo log file:

```
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (~/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 dbexit: 
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Oct 15 05:10:39.311 dbexit: really exiting now
```

So cannot change `dbpath`.

My ubuntu version:

```
# uname -a
Linux hostName 3.2.0-23-virtual #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:29:03 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem with :

`sudo mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb` and then `mongo` to access the mongodb Shell.

Answer (score 1):

What user is MongoDB running as a service?

It is usually `mongod` or `mongodb`, not root - and in fact you should not run it as root in general.  The default `dbpath` in Ubuntu is `/var/lib/mongodb` so it seems you have changed that in the config file to be `~/mongodb/db`.

If you do that, the `~` will expand to be the home folder for the user that the service is running as.  Hence you would need to create `/home/mongodb/db` or `/home/mongod/db/`, not `/root/db`, and make sure it is owned by the relevant user to use that setting.

I would recommend using a full path to eliminate the confusion.  Create a folder like `/data/mongodb/db` or similar and make sure it has the correct ownership (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232668/1148648) for more on setting permissions appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience mongodb is very picky about the locale, I had the same issues, try:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

sudo service mongodb restart
```